# x-axis display uncorrect time after a mount of time using flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, plot, charts, flot

I had a problem with `jquery flot`. I'm going to make a realtime chart. It worked as well, but after sometimes, i realized a big problem.

At the first time, everything worked as well, but after `10 minutes`, the time on `x-axis` seems later than `time` on computer.

And i didn't understand why ?

This is my demo: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kdahfkdhskfkadsf/vdukgpp7/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `setTimeout(update, 1000);` to update your graph every second and increment the x axis tick by one second. But the updating itself also takes a few milliseconds. After a few minutes this leads to a visible shift in time on the x axis.

Solution: Use the actual time to generate the tick, not some calculated value (your `now_hour` variable).